# Is the question about floating panel less unclear now?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Why isn't the floating panel focused when clicking on it?](https://superuser.com/q/1358600/301042)

Has it been clearer? If not, why is that?

PS: why is that question (which is now clearer) still bad?

Comment: Yes it's more clear, however we really can't answer/ solve it for you being missing feature/ bug. I don't think it should be reopened.

Comment: but I'm trying to understand about the underlying mechanism that make this phenomenon. In this case, it's the window manage. I think it's on-topic?

Comment: I don't think it's published why and how such mechanisms are implemented. So only answer we could give you would be to explain how its code works, there:  1 we don't have access to its source code. 2 that would be more a programming question which is again off-topic here.

Comment: If I want to investigate more but lacking sufficient knowledge, how can ask the question? Start learning how a program is coded may be overkill for my need

Comment: If you want to have a full picture on your health what you can do?  Indeed studying to be a doctor is overkill; you can just visit one and pay for the examinations. What you ask here is similar; it's way more complex for anybody to just do it free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why is that question (which is now clearer) still bad?

While you have improved the question, the underlying question still cannot be answered by the community.  You basically want to know the reason the developers of `PDF-XChange Viewer`, used a GUI element that behaves the way you describe.

While I could guess the reason, the control (bookmark panel) works the way it does, without the source code to the entire program I couldn't tell you the actual reason.  While some community members, yourself included might get some benefit from an answer which simply guesses the reason something is the case, most community members wouldn't agree with that conclusion (myself included).  I personally find answers based on assumptions to be unhelpful.

At the end of the day, knowing the reason the control works the way it does, won't change how it works.  This isn't something that can be modified.  It isn't clear what problem would be solved by knowing the reason, the bookmark panel, behaves the way it does.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you think that the question [How to know the window manager a specific program uses?](https://superuser.com/q/1359209/301042) is downvoted because it also asks for guesses? I see the answer is very useful

Comment: Please don't take it personal, I can't phrase it differently:  down votes are probably (although I haven't casted any of them) for your lack of understanding of the topic: window managers are integral parts of programs, need to consider them during development - which is generally long work of several people, even with the expertise they have it could be challenging to replace it.  Asking how you can replace it yourself at least doesn't seem serious