# Why is the question about knowing which window manager too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, close-reasons

[How to know the window manager a specific program uses?](https://superuser.com/q/1359209/301042)

Why is this question too broad? I only ask one question at a time, which is specific and answerable. I think this kind of question is very good for newbies to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the question about floating panel less unclear now?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13316/is-the-question-about-floating-panel-less-unclear-now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not something that you, as a user, can do anything about, nor should you need to care. There are too many window frameworks with too many styles that all can look very different or very similar depending on the developer who wrote the program. You cannot just edit the program to change the behaviour of one window from a user perspective.

As such you should file a bug report with the developer because that's what this is.

To why I believe your question is "too broad":

- it is vague,
- there are too many development frameworks with different window management frameworks,
- there is no information (beyond a link to your previous question) on what the program is, what the windows look like
- you give no evidence that you know how to edit your program (which you can't without source code)
- beyond your linked question there is no evidence of what you have tried or what you have found out on your own. Out of preference questions should be self contained and not require us to go hunting for back story

You are either asking for "how do I identify x for every program on the planet?" which would require an answer detailing every framework, the files it might have with the program, visual defining features, and methods or programs that can be used to hack into the program to find strings or names that might give information ***or*** you are just asking how to identify one program without saying what that program is.